# Download web images by URL from excel and save to folders in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, operating-system

I have an excel file as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.options.display.max_colwidth

df = pd.read_excel("./test.xlsx")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  city buildingName  buildingID  imgType                 imgUrl
0   bj     LG tower      123456   inside  http://pic3.nipic.com/20090629/827780_144001014_2.jpg
1   bj     LG tower      123456  outside  http://pic.baike.soso.com/p/20140321/20140321160157-391052318.jpg
2   sh          LXD      123457   inside  http://pic10.nipic.com/20101008/2634566_104534032717_2.jpg
3   gz           GM      123458   inside  http://pic1.to8to.com/case/day_120720/20120720_fb680a57416b8d16bad2kO1kOUIzkNxO.jpg
```

I need to download images by reading and iterating column `imgUrl` and save the images to the path combine by columns `city, buildingName, buildingId, imgType.`

The final output folders and subfolders' structure will be like this, they will be saved in a folder named `output`:

```
├── bj
│   └── LG tower_123456
│       ├── inside
│       │   └── 827780_144001014_2.jpg
│       └── outside
│           └── 20140321160157-391052318.jpg
├── gz
│   └── GM_123458
│       └── inside
│           └── 2634566_104534032717_2.jpg
├── sh
│   └── LXD_123457
│       └── inside
│           └── 20120720_fb680a57416b8d16bad2kO1kOUIzkNxO.jpg
```

How can I have do this in Python? Thanks for your help at advance.

I have tried to download one image:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://pic1.to8to.com/case/day_120720/20120720_fb680a57416b8d16bad2kO1kOUIzkNxO.jpg")
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("test.jpg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: There is quite a lot to do here, I would start by having a look at the documentation for `pandas` and `os` modules.  `os.mkdir()` can create a directory for example.  The pandas data frame columns can be iterated through in a number of ways, then you can create a loop, to iterate through the data frame, making directories and saving the images from the URL.  This may help too: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this assuming you have the dataframe loaded.

```
    import requests
    from os.path import join
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        url = row['url']
        file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
        r = requests.get(url)
        abs_file_name = join(row['city'],row['buildingName']+str(row['buildingId']),row['imgType'],file_name)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(abs_file_name, "wb") as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

Edited code:

```
    import requests
    from os.path import join,expanduser
    import os

    home = expanduser("~")
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # df.append({})
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        url = row['url']
        file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
        r = requests.get(url)
        filepath = join(home,row['city'],row['buildingName']+str(row['buildingId']),row['imgType'])
        if not os.path.exists(filepath):
            os.makedirs(filepath)
        filepath = join(filepath, file_name)
        # print(filepath)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(filepath, "wb") as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bj/LG tower_123456/inside/827780_144001014_2.jpg'`

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


def download_urls(csv_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path,encoding='utf-8',error_bad_lines=False)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        folder  = row[0]
        sub_folder = row[1]
        url = row[3]
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open("/{0}/{1}/{2}".format(folder, sub_folder, url.split("/")[-1]), "wb") as f:
                f.write(r.content)

path = r"C:\path\your_csv_path"
download_urls(path)
```

try this assuming you have csv file as input , there is no elegant way of iterate rows with pandas so you can use csv libary instead

Comment: Thanks, but get same error as @arajshree's solution: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/bj/LG tower/827780_144001014_2.jpg'`. Maybe I need combine `columns` together and use `subprocee` and `os` to make directories first?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os

def download_urls(csv_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path,encoding='utf-8',error_bad_lines=False)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        folder  = row[0]
        sub_folder = row[1]
        url = row[3]
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            if not os.path.exists(folder):
                os.makedirs(folder)
                if not os.path.exists(sub_folder):
                    os.makedirs(sub_folder)

            with open("/{0}/{1}/{2}".format(folder, sub_folder, url.split("/")[-1]), "wb") as f:
                f.write(r.content)

path = r"C:\path\your_csv_path"
download_urls(path)
```

try this with open folder if not exist (will open directory first only run )